# How to get information about the visualized elements in listview?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app

how can I get information from listview about it's visualized elements?
I have a ListView with messages in it, and I want to know which messages did the user read(which of them was visualized) and set a property for each message independently. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for the messages that contain a "seen" property:

```
public class VisualMessage{
  public string Message {get;set;}
  public bool Seen{get;set;}

  // Make default ToString() simply show the message
  public override string ToString(){
     return Message;
  }
}
```

Now you can use this as the source for your listview instead of plain list of messages, and you can subscribe to the change event to update the "seen" property.

Comment: Yes, the code behind part is ok, I have a seen property. The missing part is how can I get the info from ListView which element/elements from the surce collection are currently shown?